# How to install packages in just one package.json file in Yarn workspaces?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lerna

I have the classic Lerna set up. root directory, packages folder, 2 subdirectories

I want to just run `yarn install` inside one package and just to install the dependencies for this package. for some reason when I run it (even from inside this folder) it's then installing `node_modules` inside the root, packageA and packageB.

is there a solution to just allow me to install `node_modules` for a chosen directory?

Comment: Have you tried `lerna add package --scope=module` https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/add#examples?

Comment: @Clarity but I want to say add my 20 dependencies into packageA and ignore the other 5 dependencies in packageB. why is it so hard to just install dependencies in one package?

Answer (score 14):

Check out 'focused workspaces' https://classic.yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/05/18/focused-workspaces/

From inside the package you want to work on, run

```
yarn install --focus
```

and Yarn will install the local dependencies as well as any dependencies in monorepo-sibling dependencies, but *not* all dependencies across all packages in the monorepo.

Comment: At least with Yarn 1 this works only if all dependencies have been pushed to remote registry: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5864

Answer (score 6):

Do the following from the root directory:

```
yarn workspace <workspace-name> add <package-name>
```